# синтаксическая ошибка: ожидается операнд. Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Всем доброго дня!
Есть bash-скрипт, отображающий анализ тех. состояния системы:

```
#! /bin/bash
touch logfile
while true
do
echo $(date) >> logfile
var=$(uptime | tail  -17 | head -4)
cpuload=$(($var*1))
echo current cpu load is $cpuload % >> logfile 
echo $(df  –h  /  |  grep  /) >> logfile
temp=$(cat  /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
echo “current temp is $((temp/1000)) c” >> logfile
echo “----------------------------------------” >> logfile
sleep 1
done
```

Ошибка в 7 строке кода:

```
cpuload=$(($var*1))
```

./analiz.sh: строка 7: *1: синтаксическая ошибка: ожидается операнд (неверный маркер «*1»)

Буду очень признателен, если поможете.

Comment: а что, по вашей задумке, должно попасть в переменные `var` и `cpuload`? я вижу, что формируются они сейчас, мягко говоря, какими-то бредовыми конструкциями. но из этих конструкций, увы, никак не понять, что вы **хотели** туда поместить.

Comment: Код, к сожалению, не мой.  Сейчас попробую прикрепить скриншот

Comment: какой ещё скриншот??? зачем??? спросите у того, кто писал, что он хотел туда поместить. или у того кто пользуется, спросите: что он в этом месте хочет видеть.

Comment: Это на коленке написанный аналог `nagios`/`zabbix`? Не мучайте себя, настройте заточенную под это систему.